# Nested dictionary in csv convert to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, json-normalize

I tried to use `json normalize` in nested dictionary as showed in [image A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7Jty.png) and it show error `string indices must be integers`. Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

df=pd.read_csv('applied_work.csv')
df_=df.loc[:,['job_id', 'user_id', 'job_title', 'city','state']]
df_try=pd.json_normalize(data=df_try, record_path='job_title')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use
[DataFrame.from_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html)

And pay attention in the orient Parameter:

> orient{‘columns’, ‘index’}, default ‘columns’
>
> The “orientation” of the data. If the keys of the passed dict should
> be the columns of the resulting DataFrame, pass ‘columns’ (default).
> Otherwise if the keys should be rows, pass ‘index’.

Comment: not working, since data for that column is a list of dictionaries